# Disable Unity Update unless needed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a countdown effect for text elements, specifically TextMeshProUGUI. My idea is to attach a script to each TextMeshProUGUI that I want to use the effect for and just call a startEffect() method when I want to dynamically change the TextMeshProUGUI UI element.

Now, if I add that script on each of my TextMeshProUGUI elements, it would automatically invoke the Update() method on each frame. However, I only need to execute Update() for as long as the effect goes on, which is likely 1-2 seconds.

What is the best way of doing that ? I thought of maybe having a class that accepts a TextMeshProUGUI as an argument, but somehow this does now feel as "Unity"-like as having a serializable editor TextMeshProUGUI field that is just attached to each TextMeshProUGUI element. But it does have the disadvantage of running Update() for as long as the element is active, on the background.

What is the proper way of handling this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I hope to understood your question correctly. If you want to enable some effect on the object, and then disable every logic on it (forever) you can do:

```c#
public void Update(){
   //...do your logic until the end...
   enabled = false;   //This will disable this component (script) forever
}
```

If the logic can be triggered multiple times, just use a flag...

```c#
public void Update(){
   if (update_is_needed){
      //do your logic...
   }
}
```

and just ignore the overhead given by Update's invocation, is irrelevant.
I hope this helps, and not underestimates your needs.

UPDATE: Ok, I know what you're trying to do. You can do something like this (untested):

1) Declare a coroutine that will update the label:

```c#
IEnumerator IncreaseMoney(amount) {
        for (int i = actualMoney; i <= actualMoney + amount; i++)
        {
            moneyGUI.text = i.toString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

2) Invoke it (example: in an OnCollisionEnter() with the money object)

```c#
StartCoroutine (IncreaseMoney(amount));
```

As I said, I can't test it right now, hope it will be a valid starting point.
And, I assume you're coding in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Think of it as a countdown. Picture a UI element that shows the current money amount. Once a function like increaseMoney(10000) is used, the UI element should be updated. The effect would be to count up from the current money value to current_money+10000. A pretty popular effect used in games really, when money is added or removed from the current money value.

Comment: Got it! I tried to address it. I recommend to do nothing in the Update(), and not overthink about its presence.